# How to crop and resize upload images using php?

Tags: php, image

I have created form.php, upload.php and imagemanipulater.php files for crop and resize the image.

I have referenced lot in google, still i didn't get, what i need.

I need crop image and upload like gmail , like this http://s3.postimg.org/f8zu4gpsj/Untitled_1_copy.png

Now i got cropped image and saved in my uploads folder.

But i need visual crop image like gmail account.

form.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload Files using normal form and PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.php">
    <div class="row">
      <label for="fileToUpload">Select a File to Upload</label><br />
      <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

upload.php:

```
<?php
// include ImageManipulator class
require_once('imagemanipulater.php');

if ($_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'] > 0) {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'] . "<br />";
} else {
    // array of valid extensions
    $validExtensions = array('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.png');
    // get extension of the uploaded file
    $fileExtension = strrchr($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'], ".");
    // check if file Extension is on the list of allowed ones
    if (in_array($fileExtension, $validExtensions)) {
        $newNamePrefix = time() . '_';
        $manipulator = new ImageManipulator($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);
        $width  = $manipulator->getWidth();
        $height = $manipulator->getHeight();
        $centreX = round($width / 2);
        $centreY = round($height / 2);
        // our dimensions will be 200x130
        $x1 = $centreX - 100; // 200 / 2
        $y1 = $centreY - 65; // 130 / 2

        $x2 = $centreX + 100; // 200 / 2
        $y2 = $centreY + 65; // 130 / 2

        // center cropping to 200x130
        $newImage = $manipulator->crop($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2);
        // saving file to uploads folder
        $manipulator->save('uploads/' . $newNamePrefix . $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
        echo 'Done ...';
    } else {
        echo 'You must upload an image...';
    }
}
```

imagemanipulater.php:

```
<?php
class ImageManipulator
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    protected $width;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    protected $height;

    /**
     * @var resource
     */
    protected $image;

    /**
     * Image manipulator constructor
     * 
     * @param string $file OPTIONAL Path to image file or image data as string
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($file = null)
    {
        if (null !== $file) {
            if (is_file($file)) {
                $this->setImageFile($file);
            } else {
                $this->setImageString($file);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set image resource from file
     * 
     * @param string $file Path to image file
     * @return ImageManipulator for a fluent interface
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function setImageFile($file)
    {
        if (!(is_readable($file) && is_file($file))) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Image file $file is not readable");
        }

        if (is_resource($this->image)) {
            imagedestroy($this->image);
        }

        list ($this->width, $this->height, $type) = getimagesize($file);

        switch ($type) {
            case IMAGETYPE_GIF  :
                $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($file);
                break;
            case IMAGETYPE_JPEG :
                $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
                break;
            case IMAGETYPE_PNG  :
                $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($file);
                break;
            default             :
                throw new InvalidArgumentException("Image type $type not supported");
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set image resource from string data
     * 
     * @param string $data
     * @return ImageManipulator for a fluent interface
     * @throws RuntimeException
     */
    public function setImageString($data)
    {
        if (is_resource($this->image)) {
            imagedestroy($this->image);
        }

        if (!$this->image = imagecreatefromstring($data)) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Cannot create image from data string');
        }
        $this->width = imagesx($this->image);
        $this->height = imagesy($this->image);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Resamples the current image
     *
     * @param int  $width                New width
     * @param int  $height               New height
     * @param bool $constrainProportions Constrain current image proportions when resizing
     * @return ImageManipulator for a fluent interface
     * @throws RuntimeException
     */
    public function resample($width, $height, $constrainProportions = true)
    {
        if (!is_resource($this->image)) {
            throw new RuntimeException('No image set');
        }
        if ($constrainProportions) {
            if ($this->height >= $this->width) {
                $width  = round($height / $this->height * $this->width);
            } else {
                $height = round($width / $this->width * $this->height);
            }
        }
        $temp = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        imagecopyresampled($temp, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->width, $this->height);
        return $this->_replace($temp);
    }

    /**
     * Enlarge canvas
     * 
     * @param int   $width  Canvas width
     * @param int   $height Canvas height
     * @param array $rgb    RGB colour values
     * @param int   $xpos   X-Position of image in new canvas, null for centre
     * @param int   $ypos   Y-Position of image in new canvas, null for centre
     * @return ImageManipulator for a fluent interface
     * @throws RuntimeException
     */
    public function enlargeCanvas($width, $height, array $rgb = array(), $xpos = null, $ypos = null)
    {
        if (!is_resource($this->image)) {
            throw new RuntimeException('No image set');
        }

        $width = max($width, $this->width);
        $height = max($height, $this->height);

        $temp = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        if (count($rgb) == 3) {
            $bg = imagecolorallocate($temp, $rgb[0], $rgb[1], $rgb[2]);
            imagefill($temp, 0, 0, $bg);
        }

        if (null === $xpos) {
            $xpos = round(($width - $this->width) / 2);
        }
        if (null === $ypos) {
            $ypos = round(($height - $this->height) / 2);
        }

        imagecopy($temp, $this->image, (int) $xpos, (int) $ypos, 0, 0, $this->width, $this->height);
        return $this->_replace($temp);
    }

    /**
     * Crop image
     * 
     * @param int|array $x1 Top left x-coordinate of crop box or array of coordinates
     * @param int       $y1 Top left y-coordinate of crop box
     * @param int       $x2 Bottom right x-coordinate of crop box
     * @param int       $y2 Bottom right y-coordinate of crop box
     * @return ImageManipulator for a fluent interface
     * @throws RuntimeException
     */
    public function crop($x1, $y1 = 0, $x2 = 0, $y2 = 0)
    {
        if (!is_resource($this->image)) {
            throw new RuntimeException('No image set');
        }
        if (is_array($x1) && 4 == count($x1)) {
            list($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2) = $x1;
        }

        $x1 = max($x1, 0);
        $y1 = max($y1, 0);

        $x2 = min($x2, $this->width);
        $y2 = min($y2, $this->height);

        $width = $x2 - $x1;
        $height = $y2 - $y1;

        $temp = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        imagecopy($temp, $this->image, 0, 0, $x1, $y1, $width, $height);

        return $this->_replace($temp);
    }

    /**
     * Replace current image resource with a new one
     * 
     * @param resource $res New image resource
     * @return ImageManipulator for a fluent interface
     * @throws UnexpectedValueException
     */
    protected function _replace($res)
    {
        if (!is_resource($res)) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException('Invalid resource');
        }
        if (is_resource($this->image)) {
            imagedestroy($this->image);
        }
        $this->image = $res;
        $this->width = imagesx($res);
        $this->height = imagesy($res);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Save current image to file
     * 
     * @param string $fileName
     * @return void
     * @throws RuntimeException
     */
    public function save($fileName, $type = IMAGETYPE_JPEG)
    {
        $dir = dirname($fileName);
        if (!is_dir($dir)) {
            if (!mkdir($dir, 0755, true)) {
                throw new RuntimeException('Error creating directory ' . $dir);
            }
        }

        try {
            switch ($type) {
                case IMAGETYPE_GIF  :
                    if (!imagegif($this->image, $fileName)) {
                        throw new RuntimeException;
                    }
                    break;
                case IMAGETYPE_PNG  :
                    if (!imagepng($this->image, $fileName)) {
                        throw new RuntimeException;
                    }
                    break;
                case IMAGETYPE_JPEG :
                default             :
                    if (!imagejpeg($this->image, $fileName, 95)) {
                        throw new RuntimeException;
                    }
            }
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Error saving image file to ' . $fileName);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the GD image resource
     *
     * @return resource
     */
    public function getResource()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    /**
     * Get current image resource width
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getWidth()
    {
        return $this->width;
    }

    /**
     * Get current image height
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getHeight()
    {
        return $this->height;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want the user to be able to set the cropping area on the client side? If so you are going to need to write or find a javascript library to do this. In which case your question will be closed as 'too broad'.

Comment: @timclutton: Thanks .. can you help me relevant links to be able to set the cropping area on the client side using java scripts?

Comment: Please use your search engine of choice for the term 'javascript image crop', or similar. A little bit of research and effort on your part will provide a solution.

Comment: ok @timclutton: got a code easily, but its difficult to apply to my existing code.